# Memory limit on GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I think there's not enough GPU memory but what can I do? If I reduce the number of parameters of my model it will start learning but can I do it without reducing?

```
2020-11-09 22:20:23.843379: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1040] total_region_allocated_bytes_: 3032612864 memory_limit_: 3032612864 available bytes: 0 curr_region_allocation_bytes_: 6065225728
2020-11-09 22:20:23.843407: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Stats: 
Limit:                      3032612864
InUse:                      2076368128
MaxInUse:                   2076368384
NumAllocs:                         923
MaxAllocSize:                411041792
Reserved:                            0
PeakReserved:                        0
LargestFreeBlock:                    0

2020-11-09 22:20:23.843450: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:439] **************_____________***************____________******************************************____
2020-11-09 22:20:23.843498: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1767] OP_REQUIRES failed at cwise_ops_common.h:134 : Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[100352,1024] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
2020-11-09 22:45:11.359228: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1650 SUPER computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.755GHz coreCount: 20 deviceMemorySize: 4.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 178.84GiB/s
2020-11-09 22:45:11.359288: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-11-09 22:45:11.359303: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-11-09 22:45:11.359312: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-11-09 22:45:11.359331: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-11-09 22:45:11.359341: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-11-09 22:45:11.359362: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-11-09 22:45:11.359371: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-11-09 22:45:11.359415: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-11-09 22:45:11.359543: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1257] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-11-09 22:45:11.359551: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1263]      0 
2020-11-09 22:45:11.359557: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1276] 0:   N 
2020-11-09 22:45:11.359690: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1402] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 2892 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1650 SUPER, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
```

Comment: reduce your batch size. That is take in your training and validation data in batches instead of trying to load all of it at once.

Comment: I reduced it from 16 to 8 and it didn't help. Then I reduced it from 8 to 4 and it didn't help too

Comment: Full output: https://justpaste.it/7dqoi

Comment: You can try google colab for free